# .htaccess not working - Values Not Assigned Correctly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have recently started using apache, rather than nginx but my .htaccess will not work. Here is one example of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^activate2/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /activate2?user=$1&code=$2&email=$3 [QSA,L]
```

When I visit pgcp.pingrglobe.com/activate2/param1/param2/param3 - it don't work, when I visit it, and assign the values like ?user=param1&code=param2&email=param3 it works.

Any ideas about this?

Thank you.

**Current .htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.pingrglobe.com/404.html

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^blog/blogpost/(.+)$ /blog/blogpost?post=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^viewticket/(.+)/(.*)$ /viewticket?tid=$1&$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^vemail/(.+)$ /vemail?eid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^serversettings/(.+)$ /serversettings?srvid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^notification/(.+)$ /notification?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^viewreport/(.+)$ /viewreport?srvid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^removeserver/(.+)$ /removeserver?srvid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^staffviewticket/(.+)/(.*)$ /staffviewticket?tid=$1&$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^activate/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /activate?user=$1&code=$2&email=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^activate2/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /activate2?user=$1&code=$2&email=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^passwordtoken/(.+)/(.*)/(.*)$ /passwordtoken?user=$1&token=$2&email=$3 [QSA,L]
```

*solved*

Comment: Have you checked if mod_rewrite is activated?

Comment: It is, I also remove .php
I get a php error: user not found in database, which means something is happening(they're registering, but not passing because it's checking if they're set)

Comment: I can see your URL becoming http to https though I don't see that rule in current `.htaccess`. Are you sure you don't have your rules somewhere else also (another .htaccess OR apache server config)?

Comment: apache server config, and it's been solved. c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning Multiviews off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

If you have a partial name of the file (like `/activate2` for `/activate2.php`) mod_negotiation will kick in and completely bypass mod_rewrite.

---

You need this at the end of all of your rules, not the beginning:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

It's because the `-f` check also checks for path info, so your URI is being rewritten to `/activate2.php/something/something` which won't match your rule.

Comment: Not working, full version of my htaccess is here: https://p.kk7.me/qawotikoki.apache